# Prevent Orika factory from creating object for null value

Tags: java, null, jaxb, factory, orika

I have a mapping from a DTO model to a JAXB generated datamodel that is full of JAXBElement<> wrapper objects.

For example, there is a class Person defined as (getters and setters are omitted):

```
public class Person {
    private JAXBElement<Name> name;
}
```

Name is defined as:

```
public class Name {
    private String value;
}
```

For constructing JAXBElement I created an ObjectFactory:

```
public class NameFactory extends ObjectFactory<JAXBElement<Name>> {
    protected JAXBElement<Name> createObject(@Nonnull Class<?> context) {
        // here, ObjectFactory is the JAXB generated ObjectFactory
        return new ObjectFactory().createName();
    }
}
```

In my ConfigurableMapper I create a class mapping from PersonDto to Person like so:

```
factory.createClassMap(PersonDto.class, Person.class)
    .field("name", "name.value.value")
    .register;
```

With this config, the mapping of a PersonDto with no name (name equals null) will result in a Person element that has a name member with its value set to null. This is probably better explained by showing the XML that is generated after performing the class mapping:

```
<Person>
    <Name>
        <value></value>
    </Name>
</Person>
```

In my case, this XML is invalid, when there is a Name element, its value should always be non-null. The XML should therefore be:

```
<Person>
</Person>
```

Is it possible to prevent Orika from constructing the Name object, knowing its value will be set to null?

Answer (score 0):

Going through the code again a day later with a clear mind, it turns out that Orika doesn't create the wrapper element (as I expected it wouldn't) and that it was a different issue entirely...